# iCheck jQuery plugin does not send change event to original checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, icheck

I have added some checkboxes that has onChange event in order to make some action when checking or unchecking the checkboxes.

I changed the checkboxes to be iCheck, by mean of this code:

```
$('input.cbox').iCheck({
   checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green',
   radioClass: 'iradio_flat-green'
});
```

The problem I have is that when that new checkbox is checked, the onChange event is not triggered on the original chekboxes.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: why don't you use ifChanged or ifClicked [callbacks of iCheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com/#callbacks)